# Connect Linux Server to VPN

Tags: command-line, networkmanager, vpn, aws

I've got an server on AWS using Lightsail that uses Linux 4.19/Django OS/app combination. I need to use the Django framework to create a function that will take requests coming into the server, and forward them on to another API. This API is only accessible through a VPN.

I'm a bit inexperienced with the world of VPNs and Linux, so I guess my first question is, am I on the right track for this? I've tried setting up the connection to a PPTP VPN using nmcli, checking the output of the connection stored gives me this:

```
[connection]
id=myID
uuid=34a5a7b4-4af1-4224-89b5-8a488a559ce3
type=vpn
interface-name=servername.com
permissions=

[vpn]
gateway=servername.com
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
user-name=myusername

[vpn-secrets]
password=mypassword

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
bitnami@ip-172-2
```

(I've replaced the server address with servername.com) However when trying to connect to my server I get the error

```
Error: Connection activation failed: Could not find source connection.
```

Does anyone know what the cause of that issue could be? I'm unsure where to start looking to diagnose, the only thing I can think of is that I haven't specified the VPN address properly, or that I've missed it and need to include it elsewhere. It is a server name I've been provided (eg remote.company.com), rather than an IP address, so I'm not sure if that is configured differently.